# How to loop through list of instances and call a method using reduce

Tags: javascript, loops, class, oop, methods

I have a list of instances of a class. However I want to loop through this list and call the same method that they all posses using the reduce function.

Here is my class

```
class Pen {
    constructor(name, color, price){
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color; 
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    showPrice(){
        console.log(`Price of ${this.name} is ${this.price}`);
    }
}
```

This is a list of instances I have created and I have added these instances to a list

```
const PenList = []
const pen1 = new Pen("Marker", "Blue", "$3");
const pen2 = new Pen("Biro", "Red", "$4");
const pen3 = new Pen("Marker", "Green", "$5");

PenList.push(pen1, pen2, pen3)
```

I now want to use a reduce and go through each instance/element in the list and call the method showPrice.
If showPrice returns an answer that is "$5" for example, I can then print a statement or do another action.

Comment: Why `reduce`? Just use a normal `for...of` loop.

Comment: ... or `.forEach()`

Comment: `.reduce()` is (normally) used to *reduce* an array to a value. As advised by others, you should use a `for` loop or the `.forEach()` method.

Comment: would it be something like this: ```penList.forEach((item) =>  if (item.showPrice) ===  "$5"{ return ...... })```

Comment: Remove the brackets and the return statement if it's a oneliner in the if statement

Comment: penList.forEach((item) =>  if (item.showPrice) ===  "$5" ??

Comment: somewhere I think I have gotten my code wrong as the list is not correct either - nothing works

Comment: @Jennifer ... `showPrice` is not a method suited for `reduce` for the former does return the `undefined` value (thus it logs a string into the console but returns `undefined`). Any reducer function which gets applied via reducing the `PenList` array of `Pen` instances should built its logic upon a pen's `price` property.